# bibtex customize sort-field in bibtex-entry-format

Tags: formatting, bibtex, reftex-mode

I am trying to customize the behavior of `M-x bibtex-entry-format` function to reformat a bibtex entry in a bib file.

I want that the various fields in an entry are sorted to a given ordering. In my emacs init file I put this:

```
(setq bibtex-entry-format
      `(page-dashes required-fields
         numerical-fields whitespace last-comma delimiters
         unify-case sort-fields))
```

so it applies `sort-fields` to its default behavior, however, I want to customize it. How can I set my `sort-field` own criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but looking at the docstring of `bibtex-entry-format`, it says:

> `bibtex-entry-format` is a variable defined in `bibtex.el`. Its value is
> `(opts-or-alts required-fields numerical-fields)`
>
> Documentation:
> Type of formatting performed by `bibtex-clean-entry`.
> It may be t, nil, or a list of symbols out of the following:
> ...
> `sort-fields`        Sort fields to match the field order in
> `bibtex-BibTeX-entry-alist`.

My understanding is that you have to tweak `bibtex-BibTeX-entry-alist` and adapt it to your needs.